# Pandas Combine dataframes different indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2` with different indices and columns. However, there are some indices and columns overlapping.

I created a dataframe `df` with the union of the indices and of the columns: therefore there are not repeating indices or columns.

I would like to fill the dataframe `df` in the following way:

```
for x in df.index:
  for y in df.columns:
    df.loc[x,y] = df_1.loc[x,y] if (x,y) in (df_1.index,df_1.columns) else df_2.loc[x,y]
```

Can anyone tell me an efficient way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                     'E':[4,5,6],
                     'V':[7,8,9],
                     'D':[1,3,5]}, 
                     index=pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-05', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-01']))

print (df_1)
            A  D  E  V
2017-01-05  1  1  4  7
2017-01-04  2  3  5  8
2017-01-01  3  5  6  9

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                     'B':[4,5,6],
                     'C':[7,8,9]}, index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=3)) * 10

print (df_2)
             A   B   C
2017-01-01  10  40  70
2017-01-02  20  50  80
2017-01-03  30  60  90

df = df_1.combine_first(df_2)
print (df)
               A     B     C    D    E    V
2017-01-01   3.0  40.0  70.0  5.0  6.0  9.0
2017-01-02  20.0  50.0  80.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-03  30.0  60.0  90.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-04   2.0   NaN   NaN  3.0  5.0  8.0
2017-01-05   1.0   NaN   NaN  1.0  4.0  7.0
```

Comment: Amazing! Are index and columns automatically sorted? Because my index is a dates index.

Comment: I think yes, but not 100% sure, so if not add `.sort_index()`.

Comment: I test it, it nice sorts datetimeindex. also I  change sample by it.