# Merge two Series according to their index

Tags: python, pandas

After a long time of googling and not finding a solution to my, probably often asked, problem.

I have two Dataframes:

```
DF1:             DF2:
       val                 val
index            index      
  1      3        2         5
  3     10        4         15
  5     20        7         35
  6     30        8         40
```

and need an output like this:

```
DF_out:
       val 
index
  1      3 
  2      5 
  3      10 
  4      15
  5      20
  6      30 
  7      35 
  8      40
```

DF1 and DF2 should be combined and sorted according to ther indices.
Side notes:

- DF1 and DF2 never have the same index twice
- The values of the dataframes are always sequel

I would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: `pd.concat((df1,df2)).sort_index()` is what you need

Comment: or you can use `combine_first` too `df1.combine_first(df2)` : related: [Pandas Combine dataframes different indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193642/pandas-combine-dataframes-different-indices) and [
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735417/merging-2-dataframes-with-unique-index-but-same-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([DF1, DF2]).sort_index()
print (df)
       val
index     
1        3
2        5
3       10
4       15
5       20
6       30
7       35
8       40
```